# Error: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKCoreKit"

Tags: ios, cordova, cocoapods, fbsdk

I am trying to build a simple Cordova app for iOS, but running `pod install` fails with the following error:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKCoreKit":
  In Podfile:
    CordovaPluginsStatic (from `../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins`) was resolved to 2.4.2, which depends on
      FBSDKCoreKit (= 5.15.0)

    CordovaPluginsStatic (from `../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins`) was resolved to 2.4.2, which depends on
      FBSDKShareKit (= 5.15.0) was resolved to 5.15.0, which depends on
        FBSDKShareKit/Share (= 5.15.0) was resolved to 5.15.0, which depends on
          FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.0)
```

As far as I understand, `FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.0)` should actually match `= 5.15.0` so it looks like CocoaPods fails to figure this out.

How do I troubleshoot this?

CocoaPods: `1.10.0`

Comment: After creating a new Cordova app just with this plugin, `pod install` succeeded with no errors :shrug: Could be CocoaPods had an issue with its cache and `pod install`ing in a new project helped to clean it out.